# How can add path of mysql 8 in environment variables?

Tags: mysql, environment-variables

I have installed MySQL along with mysql shell, mysql server, workbench
How can I add path of mysql in environment variables?

But which folder I should use?

[image]

Comment: `C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/bin`

Answer (score 0):

Look up Environment Variables from the Start menu. Add the \bin folder to the path; sort of like this:
[image]